# Can I confine Google Maps searches within a complex shape?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I volunteered to help out the local Rescue Squad with a problem they're having with their GPS's. When they receive data from a patient, they don't always get City/Town/ZIP information, so they basically have to type in a street number and a street name and pick between three different choices from various Cities/Towns in our district.

The issue is that they know some areas in which the wont be dispatched (certain towns or zip codes) and would like to limit their search to only places in the district defined. I want to know, before embarking on my own mapping/coordinating/javascript adventure, is there a way to limit the boundaries in the Google-Maps API to our district? It wouldn't be a simple shape, but more like a complex polygon (with some "donuts" within...).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [viewport biasing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Viewports) when geocoding the street.